# Express the given expression as a single logarithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Express $$2 \ln (2 - x) + 3 \ln (x^2 - 5)$$ as a single logarithm.

Can anyone help me with this question? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using properties of logarithms we have

$$a\ln b=\ln b^a$$
and $$\ln x+\ln y=\ln xy$$

We get

> $$\begin{align} 2 \ln (2 - x) + 3 \ln (x^2 - 5)&= \ln (2 - x)^2 + \ln (x^2 - 5)^3\\&=\ln \Big[(2 - x)^2(x^2 -5)^3\Big]\\\end{align}$$

Comment: Why do you expand ? The second line is much nicer (at least to me). Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

$$\large\color{blue}2 \ln \color{green}{(2 - x)} + \color{red}3 \ln \color{orange}{(x^2 - 5)}
=\ln\color{green}{(2 - x)}^{\color{blue}2}\color{orange}{(x^2 - 5)}^{\color{red}3}$$